# Viewmodel Livedata doesn't update data observers

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

For example, I have 12 `UpcomingGamesFragment` and each fragment has a different set of game data releasing a month, for example the first fragment of 12 will have video games releasing on January 2019.

In my app, there's a navigation drawer with a list of platforms (ps4, xbox, pc, etc.) and when the user picks his consoles by clicking on the check boxes and then closes the drawer layout, I want all the fragments to update accordingly. Like only show games releasing on these platforms. Retrieve and filter successfully works through a method in `UpcomingGamesFragment` called `loadReleasesData()`

Now what I want is all the fragments to update when the navigation drawer gets closed, because my implementation doesn't work, please tell me what's wrong.

Here's my ViewModel class:

```
public class ReleasesViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<List<_Release>> upcomingReleases = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public ReleasesViewModel() { }

    public MutableLiveData<List<_Release>> getUpcomingReleases() {
        return upcomingReleases;
    }
}
```

And in my Filter drawer layout is in my MainActivity, and also I declare my ViewModel in my MainActivity:

OnCreate (A lot of code omitted for clarity)

```
mReleasesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ReleasesViewModel.class);
```

My drawer layout on close:

```
@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View drawerView) {
    // If change detected refresh!
    if (!mCopyOfUserPlatforms.equals(SharedPrefManager.read(SharedPrefManager.PLATFORM_IDS, mDefaultPlatformsSet))) {
        mReleasesViewModel.getUpcomingReleases().setValue(new ArrayList<_Release>());
    }
}
```

And I pass the viewmodel livedata object to my 12 fragments when I initialize them in another fragment called the `ViewPagerFragment` here's how:

onCreateView:

```
   // Get the ViewModel
    ReleasesViewModel releasesViewModel = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mReleasesViewModel;
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        UpcomingGamesFragment upcomingGamesFragment = new UpcomingGamesFragment();
        upcomingGamesFragment.setLiveData(releasesViewModel); // HERE 
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(upcomingGamesFragment, title, queryId);
    }
```

This is my setLiveData() method in UpcomingGamesFragment:

```
public void setLiveData(ReleasesViewModel releasesViewModel) {
    releasesViewModel.getUpcomingReleases().observe(this, new android.arch.lifecycle.Observer<List<_Release>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<_Release> releases) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Refreshing this baby boy...");
            loadReleaseData(0);
        }
    });
}
```

How I know the livedata doesn't update all my fragments? It is because I have a log in my loadReleasesData method and it doesn't get printed in the Logcat and not to mention the fact it doesn't update the fragment(s). Have a good day and bye! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not with `LiveData` but with `ViewModel` instance you're getting in `ViewPagerFragment` :

use this in your `onCreateView()` of fragment:

```
ReleasesViewModel releasesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ReleasesViewModel.class);
```

instead of your code:

```
// Get the ViewModel
ReleasesViewModel releasesViewModel = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mReleasesViewModel;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work, it doesn't update

Comment: Can you say just for confirmation : Are you using viewmodel in fragment class where you want to receive data? @Johnny boy

Comment: I;m using it, but maybe not in a good way. How do you want me to use it?

Comment: Use `ReleasesViewModel releasesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ReleasesViewModel.class);` this line in the `Fragment` you want to receive `LiveData`, for your instance, it will be in `UpcomingGamesFragment` and register to `LiveData` in that fragment too.